# Text and images in UiTextView

Tags: ios, image, uitextview

I am working on a chat process where I need to place smileys and text together on the textbox, this part is done with no problems, the place where I am stuck is - if is want to place an image in between any text by dragging the cursor to a specified place, then how can this be done.

Right now I can place the image right after the text.

for eg: in my uitextbox -> [ Hi! how r u ? 'image' ]...
         but if I want to do like this [ Hi! 'image' how r u ]....I should be able to select a position in textbox by dragging the cursor there and then select and place the image there..

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: How do you place images? With `NSAttributedString` and `NSTextAttachement`?

Comment: Yes they have placed the image in between like this "NSMakeRange(6, 1)" but how do I track the place between the cursor..since there is no event in uitextview for text changed or cursor focus

Comment: You have to know where is the cursor, and use it for the range.

Comment: YOu need to configure that yourself.. a lot of work but possible.. good luck.. hahaha..

Comment: Oyeoj, thank you..I am done with this and have posted the my answer as to how to achieve this thing...:)

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured out the solution for this... the above can be achieved using "UITextRange" and "UITextPosition" for the selected area in the UItextView. :)